# How do I get the sum of object methods in a Rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

In my application, I am using CarrierWave for file attachments. I have a FileAttachment model and can get the file's size by doing:

```
file = FileAttachment.first
file.attachment.size
```

In a Rails query, you can sum columns by doing:

```
Model.sum(:integer_column)
```

With CarrierWave, the `.attachment` method returns on object with one of its values of `.size`.

How can I do a `sum` query of `FileAttachment.attachment.size`?

For now, this is my solution:

```
FileAttachment.sum { |file_attachment| file_attachment.attachment.size }
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Unless you [save the file size to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785094/carrierwave-rails-3-s3-save-the-file-size-to-the-database), there's no better option than going through records and summing the way you did

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question. You would like to sum sizes of all attachments of some resource.. I am guessing that you would like to do something like: `your_resource.file_attachments.map{|fa| fa.attachment&.size}.compact.sum`

Comment: No need to map.sum - sum also accepts a block. And to deal with nil, you can just convert it to number, which will give you 0, which won't affect the sum. So the code becomes `your_resource.file_attachments.sum { |fa| fa.attachment&.size.to_f }`